# Intercept ALL services

Tags: c#, autofac

We have small lifetime scopes in our applications. It would be interesting to be able to intercept all services registered in autofac. By doing so we can see exactly which path the code takes for every lifetime scope and which method arguments are used. Not really usable for production but when really great for debugging/diagnostics/refactoring as you ge the whole picture and not just unit level.

But AFAIK it's only possible to register an interceptor for each single registration?

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing like this is supported out of the box with the Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 library.** You could potentially implement something like a module that handles [OnActivating](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) for every component using code similar to the stuff in Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2, but you'll run into trouble like...

- **Do you want class interceptors or interface interceptors?** The type of service being resolved vs. the limit type of the component backing it will influence what kind of dynamic proxy you want to make. I believe the current A.E.D2 code only generates interception for either/or - not every interface a class implements, etc.
- **Do you use WCF client proxies?** Client proxies are an interesting beast of their own so you have to special-case them. You'll see that in A.E.D2.

Generally problems like this get solved by aspect-oriented programming solutions (e.g., [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/)) or profilers (e.g., [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/))... or a combination of both. You might want to look into those solutions if you have the ability.

For an example of what sort of module implementation I'm talking about, [check out the log4net integration page on the Autofac wiki](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration). That shows how to handle OnPreparing for every component in the system. You can do the same thing, but handle OnActivating instead and [use the sample on the Lifetime Events wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) to show you how to swap one resolved thing for another (swap the real object for the generated proxy).